# How to name a pandas Series column title?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set the title for a `pd.Series`, such that when assigning it to `pd.Dataframe`s it goes along with its title.

I searched and couldn't find anything. Best I could do was name the index, but not the data column.

Here is what I have

```
import pandas as pd


s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=[5, 6, 7, 8])
s.name = "a"
s.rename("b", inplace=True)

s.index.name = "c"
print("____")
print(s)
```

output:

> ```
> ____
> c
> 5    1
> 6    2
> 7    3
> 8    4
> Name: b, dtype: int64
> ```

I want the `1, 2, 3, 4` column to be named.

Comment: `s.name='something'`. If you want that placed over the data, you need to turn the series to a dataframe `s.to_frame(name='something')` or `s.reset_index(name='something')`.

Comment: If you want a column header, you need a Dataframe instead of a Series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did well, but you can directly pass it in the constructor

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=[5, 6, 7, 8], name="my_amazing_name")
print(s)

# ---------------------------------------------
5    1
6    2
7    3
8    4
Name: my_amazing_name, dtype: int64
```

If you use them to build a `DataFrame` (or append to it), it'll keep it's name

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=[5, 6, 7, 8], name="my_amazing_name_1"),
    pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=[5, 6, 7, 8], name="my_amazing_name_2"),
    pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=[5, 6, 7, 8], name="my_amazing_name_3"),
]).T
print(df)

# ---------------------------------------------
   my_amazing_name_1  my_amazing_name_2  my_amazing_name_3
5                  1                  1                  1
6                  2                  2                  2
7                  3                  3                  3
8                  4                  4                  4
```

Comment: I really think your column names are amazing.

Comment: @piRSquared I wanted to suuuure that the OP sees them :D